# Increasing the font size in the Vertexlabels of GraphPlot

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I have the following code and corresponding output:

```
GraphPlot[Table[i -> Mod[3^i, 5], {i, 20}], VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

I wish to do two things:

1) Increase the font size of the numbers

2) Convert the the yellow boxes to larger circles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GraphPlot[Table[i -> Mod[3^i, 5], {i, 20}], 
          VertexRenderingFunction -> 
           Function[{r, v}, {Yellow, Disk[r, 0.2], Style[Text[v, r], Black, 16]}]
         ]
```

[image]

Comment: Just missing out on  the black coloured outline for the yellow circles....great otherwise

Comment: Insert `EdgeForm[Black]` at the start of the list of graphics commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify font options as the `PlotStyle` option setting:

```
gp = GraphPlot[Table[i -> Mod[3^i, 5], {i, 20}], VertexLabeling -> True, 
    PlotStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontColor -> Red}]
```

[image]

To change vertex shapes from rectangle to disk, you can also post-process `gp` as follows:

```
ClearAll[modify]
modify[r_: .2, es_: RGBColor[0.94, 0.85, 0.36], fs_: RGBColor[1, 1, 0.8]] := 
  Replace[#, Text[Framed[x_, ___], y_] :> {EdgeForm[es], FaceForm[fs], 
      Disk[y, r], Text[x, y]}, Infinity] &;

modify[] @ gp
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the newer [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) for this.

```
Graph[
 Table[i -> Mod[3^i, 5], {i, 20}],
 VertexSize -> 0.6,
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 VertexLabelStyle -> 18, (* this sets the font size *)
 VertexStyle -> ColorData["Legacy", "LemonChiffon"],
 EdgeStyle -> Darker@ColorData["Legacy", "IndianRed"]
]
```

Add `DirectedEdges -> False` if you want to interpret `->` as an undirected edge.

[image]

If you like the style of `GraphPlot`, and want to use it as a starting point with `Graph`, add the option `GraphStyle -> "ClassicDiagram"`.